# Enemy doesn't fire at player

Tags: unity, c#

My script looks pretty good but it says `Target` variable has not been assigned value.

```
public GameObject AntagonisticElement;
public GameObject Target;
public float bulletSpeed;
public float enemySpeed;
public float bulletDestroyTime;
public GameObject explsn;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public Transform bulletSpawn;

Vector3 pos;

public float min = 20;
public float max = 10;

public int MaxCounter;
public int CounterStatus;
int numberofEnemy;
// Use this for initialization

void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (CounterStatus <= 0)
    {
        if (numberofEnemy < 3)
        {
            Vector3 creationPoint = transform.position;
            creationPoint.y = -0.5f;
            Instantiate(AntagonisticElement, creationPoint, transform.rotation);

            CounterStatus = MaxCounter;
            numberofEnemy++;
        }
    }


    else
    {
        CounterStatus--;
    }

    transform.LookAt(Target.transform.position);

    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Target.transform.position) >= min)
    {
        transform.position += transform.forward * 4 * Time.deltaTime;

    }
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Target.transform.position) <= max)
    {
        shootAt();
    }

}

    void shootAt()
    {

        Instantiate(explsn, bulletSpawn.position, bulletSpawn.transform.rotation);
        var bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletSpawn.position, bulletSpawn.rotation);
        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = bullet.transform.forward * bulletSpeed;



    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to gamedev! have you assigned your `Target` in the inspector?

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't be completely sure without seeing your script in the inspector, have you made sure to drag and drop a GameObject into the Target slot in your inspector?

If you want to do this in the script you could also find it by reference with:

```
void Start () {
     Target = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Target");
 }
```

Comment: same again. in inspector you mean when i click script what it shows in inspectr for target? it is none

Comment: You must drag something there otherwise Target will be empty. If you are trying to make the enemy shoot at the player, drag the player object into empty Target space in the inspector.

Comment: Or some variant of `GameObject.Find` or use the physics messages or...

Comment: I chose myplayer asset when click on target there opens select an assset i chose my player

Comment: again it keep the same error

Comment: how to drag it into target slt in inspector?

Comment: You can drag the GameObject from your hierarchy or assets and drop it into the script you have made in the space next to Target that says None.

Comment: Let me know if that helped? Did you manage to drag it in?